# Sqlyog not connected to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, ssh, 22.04, mysql

Trying connect to mysql database with SQLYOG latest version but got this error message

```
"SSH ERROR: Fatal error network error : connection timed out"
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. There is not enough information here to answer your question. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu that you are using (1) whether the MySQL database is on the same system as SQLYOG (2) whether you have created an appropriate MySQL user (3) whether you are using an appropriate SSH user. With this, it may be possible to identify the actual problem and offer a solution 

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [Webyog.com](http://faq.webyog.com/content/22/113/en/ssh-error-messages.html)

> "FATAL ERROR: Network ERROR: connection timeout". Network TimeOut (as
> it says) or simply could not establish contact to a SSH daemon on the
> URL specified. You even get this if the computer you are trying to
> contact is not available at all or offline. Also this error happens if
> you are using public/private key authentication and the keys are not
> valid. Keys used by SQLyog must be in .ppk -format (same as used by
> the 'Putty' program)."